# How to Select all codes between Curly Braces in Notepad++?

Tags: if-statement, selection, notepad++, highlight

In Notepad++ How to select all (Highlight) codes between Curly braces (Start & End)? For eg. If-else, Method definition, While, For loop etc. I remember similar option is available with Adobe Dreamweaver where we can perform this CTRL ' (Holding the control key & single quote together). In Notepad++ How to achieve the same?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: [selection between matching braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705148/notepad-add-selection-between-matching-braces-feature)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From Notepad++ v6.4.4: This feature got added in -  `Add selection between matching braces feature.`

**How to achieve :**

Select a curly brace `{` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to highlight the section.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Considering it's your own question, can you change it?

Answer (score 4):

At Settings->Preferences->Delimiter, change the delimiters from parentheses to braces and check the multi-line box.  Then you can Ctrl-double-click on either brace to highlight everything in between.

Also, to jump between braces you can use Ctrl-b.

Comment: Just to clarify: selecting with Ctrl-double-click works for only one pair of delimiters, but you can choose any characters as delimiters, even letters, and they do not have to be matching.

On the other hand, jumping with Ctrl-b and selecting with Ctrl+Alt+b work for the matching braces, square brackets and parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the help of this attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor at the starting of the curly brace, it will go `red` and together its `complementy will also go red`, locate this red closing curly brace, hold your `shift key` and click on this closing red brace. you code will be selected ...

Comment: Thanks @lord_linus But My actual Problem, I couldn't find the closing brace since the code has 5000+ lines. Is there no other way to select whole code within the braces?

Comment: When you will have a simple overview of the code then this will be catchy to your eyes directly, and also you see a - sign in front of the first curly brace, you can compress with that also,