# Notepad++ Add selection between matching braces feature?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ just released a new update, v6.4.4:

One of the new features listed is:
10. Add selection between matching braces feature.

What does that mean? Sounds useful if I can figure it out.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here; you might try on the [Notepad++ forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about new feature in NOtepad++

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think following is this feature

Select a curly brace `{` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to highlight the section.

It can be accessed through Search -> "Select All between Matching Braces"

[image]

Comment: Can I say, that menu font is both awesome and insane.

Comment: I would say just insane :)

Comment: I really appreciate the feature, very useful. But was expecting CTRL+SHIFT+B instead to be consistent with the CTRL+SHIFT+ARROW feature.